# Pass data from express route into node module export function

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I am new to node, I think I need to use middleware, but I can't warp my head around what it is actually used for, or if this is where it is meant to be used. I have data that is being posted from my view into an express route.

**ROUTE - route.js**

```
var GetPlayer = require('./models/getPlayer.js');
module.exports = function(app) {    
app.post('/api/getPlayer', function(req, res) {
        //GetPlayer.apiGetPlayer(req.body.username);
        console.log(req.body.username); //this logs the correct data
    });
}
```

but now I need to pass that data into a node api call and send that response back to the client. But I can not get the route to call that function or pass the data into it.

**MODULE.EXPORT - getPlayer.js**

```
module.exports = {
    apiGetPlayer: function(error, res) {
        console.log("in get player");
        console.log(res);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would only want to use an Express middleware if this is something you want to do for more than one route (ie. parsing request body's from JSON to actual Object using [body-parser](https://npmjs.com/package/body-parser)).  That seems like it could be overkill based on the supplied code. One way to approach this is to just take the username and pass a callback function in to getPlayer. Then when the callback function passed to `apiGetPlayer()` returns, respond back to the requester based on the result of `apiGetPlayer()`.

#### getPlayer.js

```
module.exports = 
    // callback is an error-first callback function
    apiGetPlayer: function(username, callback) {
        let err;
        let player;

        // Logic for getting player go here

        // If an error occurs return an error to the callback
        if (err)
            return callback(err, null);

        return callback(null, player);
    }
}
```

#### /api/getPlayer route

```
app.post('/api/getPlayer', (req, res) => {
    GetPlayer.apiGetPlayer(req.body.username, (err, player) => {
        if (err)
            return res.status(500).send(err);

        return res.status(200).send(player);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For my own knowledge then, middleware in express can be comparable to using services in angular? Basically used for something that you will call multiple times throughout different routes?

Comment: They're not comparable things. Express Middleware sort of follow the Decorator Pattern, so each Middleware is a Decorator of sorts for your Express App. Angular Services are just Singleton Objects that provide additional functionality & data via Dependency Injection.

Comment: I am to the point of needing the callback, however it is telling me that callback is either not defined, or callback is not a function..